# Color your partitions by parity

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

Let $a_c(n)$ be the number of ways to partition a positive integer $n$ where each even part comes in $c$ colors. Then, we can supply the generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq0}a_c(n)q^n=\prod_{k\geq1}\frac1{(1-q^k)(1-q^{2k})^{c-1}}.$$
In particular, $a_1(n)=p(n)$ is the usual number of (unrestricted) partitions of $n$; $a_2(n)$ is the so-called [cubic partitions](https://oeis.org/A002513) of $n$.

**Example.** $a_2(2)=\#\{{\color{red}2},2,11\}=3, a_2(4)=\#\{{\color{red}4},4,31,{\color{red}{22}},{\color{red}2}2,22,{\color{red}2}11,211,1111\}=9$.

Experiments suggest the below congruences.

> **QUESTION.** Are these statements true?

$\bullet$ $a_2(3n+2)\equiv0\pmod 3$

$\bullet$ $a_4(5n+4)\equiv0\pmod 5$

$\bullet$ $a_3(7n+4)\equiv0\pmod 7$

$\bullet$ $a_5(11n+10)\equiv0\pmod{11}$.

Comment: This is very similar to [Ramanujan's congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_congruences). Have you tried to adapt a proof of those?

Comment: You are right, it seems the natural course but it is easier said than done.

Comment: The modulo 3 result is proven in H.-C. Chan, Ramanujan’s cubic continued fraction and ananalog of his “most beautiful identity”, Int. J. Number Theory 6 no.3 (2010), 673–680.

Comment: @BrianHopkins: thank you.